# Is it possible to create a custom home screen launcher in google tv?

Tags: android, google-tv

Is it possible to create my own custom home application on google tv?

Comment: Its hard to say without a release yet but if it is Android, like the phones, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - same way as in android phones.